# Memory usage limit for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

What is the application memory usage limit of windows phone 8 application, I need memory limit for the three different devices available (like 720p, WXVGA etc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The zen of WP8 memory caps has three aspects: default baseline (150MB+), extended memory (180MB+) and low-memory device opt-out (300MB+).

**Baseline:**

By default all apps (D3D, XAML and XNA) on WP8 have at least 150MB which is up from 90MB on WP7. The increase from 90MB to 150MB is done to accommodate the extra memory needed for more detailed visuals on HD displays.

**Extended Memory Caps**

Apps can also ask for additional memory by specifying ID_FUNCCAP_EXTEND_MEM. When asking for additional memory you're guaranteed at least 180MB on all devices. When asking for additional memory your app may actually get all the way up to 380MB memory on high-memory devices.

**Low memory device opt-out**

Apps can also opt-out of low-memory devices (512MB RAM) by specifying ID_REQ_MEMORY_300. That guaranteed your app will only run on high-memory devices (more then 1GB of RAM) and with at least 300MB of memory.

The way you should think about "high memory devices" is that it's just like having an optional sensor (Gyroscope, Compass, etc) or any other optional hardware (NFC, etc). Don't assume users have this extra memory unless you want to limit the distribution of your app considerably. Public statistics show that low-memory devices sell pretty well and you shouldn't disqualify your app from those devices unless it's an absolute must.

Answer (score 1):

[App memory limits for Windows Phone 8 (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)